# Query to find or select the random or different number in organize numbers of 2 column of same table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

How can I compare two column and find the random number or the number that isn’t similar between the column of the same table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PArU.png)

Comment: Your data is incomplete.  You need to _also_ have another column which imposes the ordering you showed us.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite? You shouldn't have both tags.

Comment: ok understood, I am using SQLite, I think, I have to modify the question and the table

Comment: Why is it non-sequential? I.e., in what sense is it non-sequential?

Comment: I have updated the question, here I wrote that the number that is added in second column isn't similar to that of 1st column

Answer (score 1):

## MySQL and SQLite Version:

'T2 and T3 data is null' means not sequential.

because first left join T2 : 34 + 1 (35) there is no data in TestTable

second left join T3 : 34 - 1 (33) there is no data in TestTable

So we can get 'which one is not sequential'

```
select T1.Number from TestTable T1
left join TestTable T2 on T2.Number = T1.Number + 1 
left join TestTable T3 on T3.Number = T1.Number - 1
where T2.Number is  null and T3.Number is  null
```

---

```
| Number |
|--------|
|     34 |
|   3234 |
|     32 |
```

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6ed2a/1/0)

---

Hope it help you :-)

---

> can you tell me what T1.Number + 1 means?

#### example:

T1.number is 34 and it is sequential

T1.Number + 1 = 35 , `left join TestTable T2 on T2.Number = T1.Number + 1`
should return not null

Comment: This assumes that the column in fact only has 5 rows, and that `33` and `35` do not appear somewhere.  You should state this assumption.

Comment: The right idea, but one `left join` is probably sufficient for the OP's question.